# trying to float the body in html and stopping it from resizing when adding more elements to it

Tags: html, css

So I have two questions. The first is that I'm working on a web page and all I want is to have the body floating in the html with a padding of 10px all around. This is great-works fine as long as I put nothing else in the body. Once I do, the bottom margin I guess "expands" because the contents within the body - do I have that right? Well anyway, I need for that not to happen. Basically, picture an empty html page, then picture a white box right in the middle. That's the body and I need it to stay that way.

I've looked all over Google and found some examples using position: absolute, setting height to 100%, etc. Each time I begin to add the actual contents for the page, the bottom margin moves down. Is there a way for it to not do that?

My second question is that I also have a div (content), and inside that div are two other divs - one floated left and the other floated right. When I set content to display: inline-block, the two divs look perfect and content is the width of the div its inside. But when I remove it from the content div and make both the left and right divs display:inline-block, they aren't exactly inside the content div. Why is that? Here's my code below. Thanks for a point in the right direction...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header></header>
            <div class="statement"></div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="page_content">
                    <div id="left_side">
                        some stuff
                    </div>          
                    <div id = "right_side">
                        some stuff
                    </div>          
                    <p></p>         
                </div>  <!-- END page content -->
            </div> <!-- END wrapper -->         
            <footer></footer>
        </div> <!-- END wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    border: 2px groove white;
    background-color: #545454;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px groove red;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 100%;
}   
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 2px groove green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
header {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px groove blue;
}
.statement {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px groove orange;
}
#page_content {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px groove yellow;
}
#left_side {
    border: 2px groove purple;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#right_side {
    border: 2px solid maroon;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're confusing concepts, `html` isn't an element to play around as you are doing, just think of it as a container that will get the viewport size, don't force it to behave like something else. And same goes for `body`

Once you fix that, you can easily work with with your `#wrapper` div

See how your CSS looks with a bit of cleaning up:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px groove white;
    background-color: #545454;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 2px groove green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
header {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px groove blue;
}
.statement {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px groove orange;
}
#page_content {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px groove yellow;
    padding:30px;
}
#right_side:after {
    content:'';
    clear:both;
    float:none
}
#left_side {
    border: 2px groove purple;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
#right_side {
    border: 2px solid maroon;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

You can [see a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jrqsv391/)

In that fiddle, I've also changed it to answer your second question. If you use floats, you don't need the `inline-block` elements, but yo need to clear the floats at some point or the containing element will never close. In this case, I achieve that by adding this:

```
#right_side:after {
    content:'';
    clear:both;
    float:none
}
```

But you can also add this to your HTML, right after your floated divs (where you have those empty `<p></p>`:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

then in your CSS:

```
.clear{clear:both; float: none;}
```

this is a very easy to use method and probably the most commonly used, but both of them will work equally

Comment: `html` and `body` *are* proper block boxes. Some properties behave differently on the root element, such as `float` having no effect, but for most purposes it is entirely OK to style these elements. `body` behaves exactly like a regular `div` or other block element and can therefore be floated.

Comment: yes, OK, that's the theory, but we're talking of "real life" (so to speak), where you apply only general styles to html, then a bit less general to body and then you style elements by its purpose. I bet there are no more than 0,00001% of sites defining html width (and I'm sure this is an overestimate to play safe), and of those that apply width to body, 99,9999999% apply the "width:100%" rule. Again, theory is fine, but we need to talk about application